# Trying to dual boot ubuntu 13.10 and windows 8.1 on my laptop however ubuntu installer doesnt pick up windows 8.1

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-8

I have my bootable USB, my secure boot turned off, and have managed to boot into 'trying ubuntu' and begin the install process.

however when I reach the tab that asks how i would like to install for example erase everyting and install, something else, etc. It says that no other OS is detected on the computer.

My worry is that if i proceed with something else and install anyway GRUB wont allow me to boot into windows 8.1.

Anyone encountered this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you turned fast boot off? Is this an ultrabook with Intel SRT uses RAID and needs that off also and meta-data removed from drives.

Answer (score 1):

1.On the ubuntu installation wizard.select **something else** option.
2.Allocate the space for your Ubuntu 13.10 partition.
3.Once booted up run the command `sudo update-grub` on terminal.

you don't worrry about that grub will allow you to boot into windows 8.1 os.If this method not worked then download and run `boot-repair disk`,select recommended repair option.This will reinstall or update your grub.